# visual c++ Serialport class handling data very slow

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I'm trying to handle data recieved at about 1Hz from a robot through a serialport (bluetooth connection). I will recieve data with different headers determining what data will be recieved and what the expected length of the message is.

for example:
Header: sensorvalues (0x32) -> expected length 11 incl. header.

First i want to check if the byte is a header and if thats the case extract the expected length (in bytes).

I am using vc++ and the serialport class in the GUI. 
The "seirialport->read(buffer, 0, expected length)" is very slow and not very reliable. I found some tips at http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport but the buffer still builds up to the point where I have about 200 bytes in the buffer, which is not very good when i need live sensorvalues displayed on the GUI.

The key parts of my code are:

```
System::Void MyForm::serialPort1_DataReceived_1(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e) {
if (serialPort1->BytesToRead > 0){
    if (write_position == 0){
        serialPort1->BaseStream->ReadAsync(data_recieved_buffer, 0, 1);
        header = data_recieved_buffer[0];
        if (this->InvokeRequired){
            myrecievedata_delegate^ d = gcnew myrecievedata_delegate(&myrecievedata);
            this->Invoke(d, gcnew array < Object^ > {'h'});
        }
        else
        {
            myrecievedata('h');
        }
    }
    else if (this->serialPort1->BytesToRead > expected_length - 1)
    {
        serialPort1->BaseStream->ReadAsync(data_recieved_buffer, 0, expected_length - 1);
        if (this->InvokeRequired){
            myrecievedata_delegate^ d = gcnew myrecievedata_delegate(&myrecievedata);
            this->Invoke(d, gcnew array < Object^ > {'b'});
        }
        else
        {
            myrecievedata('b');
        }
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

and the recieved data is sent to

```
System::Void MyForm::myrecievedata(char status){
if (status == 'h'){
    handleheader(header);
}
else if (status == 'b'){
    handlebyte();
}
```

Is the problem at the serialport_datarecieved event? I can only think of invoke (which I have very little knowledge about) being the problem, still keeping the work in the serialport thread. 
If that is the case how would I make sure that the data is handled in a different thread?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your use of [`AsyncRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream.readasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) is correct? Shouldn't you be waiting until the async operation finishes before trying to access the data?

Comment: How would i do that? I thought that AsyncRead had the BeginRead and EndRead internally... Do i need a way to check if the Async operation is finished?

Comment: It seems like the `await` keyword will do the trick: https://paoloseverini.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/async-await-in-c/

Comment: it seems that <pplawait> does not support CLR projects! So the question is if there might be another way to get around the problem in visual c++!